# Actionscript 3 - fl.controls.UIScrollBar - setting scrollPosition does not work

Tags: actionscript

I have a scroll bar ( fl.controls.UIScrollBar ), which i create dynamically in a class, and add it to the stage.

```
public class Slider extends Sprite
{
    private var scroll:UIScrollBar = new UIScrollBar();
    // etc.

    // constructor
    addChild(scroll);
    scroll.setSize(15.75, 205.3);
    scroll.direction = ScrollBarDirection.HORIZONTAL;
    scroll.setScrollProperties(150, minScrollPos, maxScrollPos,snapInterval);
    scroll.addEventListener(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, scrollHandler);
}
```

Then, I try to call

```
    scroll.scrollPosition = 30;
```

My method call will not update the scroll thumb.Any ideas why?

Comment: Thank you, that was great!I am new here, i cannot push the up button.I will, as soon as i receive some points.

Answer (score 0):

Salut Mihai,

I found that odd at first. I expected setting the value would suffice.
If I set scrollPosition in an enter frame loop, it works, but not if I use the setter straight away. This probably means that if you make the calls right after creating/setting up the component, internally, it's not ready yet. UIComponents(like UIScrollBar) have a whole lifecycle to deal with. Jeff Kamerer has a nice set of [devnet articles](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components.html) on this, if you're interested.

Long story short, the component is not ready right away, so the best bet is to wait for it to be ready by listening to the [RENDER](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#RENDER) event:

```
scroll.addEventListener(Event.RENDER,rendered);
function rendered(event:Event):void {
    scroll.removeEventListener(Event.RENDER,rendered);
    scroll.scrollPosition = 30;
}
```